# Mass file extraction

Tags: 7-zip

System info:

```
aggitan@moneque:~$ uname -a
Linux moneque 2.6.32-25-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 17 20:05:27 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux

aggitan@moneque:~$ 7z

7-Zip 9.04 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-05-30
p7zip Version 9.04 (locale=en_US.utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)
```

I've got a folder that has 68 archives in it ranging from .rar, .ace, & .zip.

I want to extract all of these files using their folder name as the first directory ("Extract here")

If I use file-roller it halts at the first error, there doesn't appear to be an "ignore error" flag for file roller.

If I use 7zip it dumps everything into the current folder and doesn't use clean folders

How can I extract everything into separate folders without spilling everything into the current directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for i in *; do mkdir "$i.extracted"; (cd "$i.extracted" && 7z x "../$i") || echo "Error with $i"; done`

Comment: Make this `for i in *; do mkdir "$i.extracted"; (cd "$i.extracted" && 7z x "../$i"); done`. That way, if `cd` fails for a particular directory, `7z` doesn't set to work in the current directory.

Comment: @Gilles: good point, thanks. Also added a error message (hope my brackets are correct)

Comment: @Tobias: With the parentheses, you don't need `cd ..`: the parentheses create a subshell, and the directory change is local to that subshell.

Comment: @Gilles: once again I learned something new, thank you

Comment: This did it for me, thank you. I cross posted to askubuntu should I link to this, copy paste your answer or can you post there? http://askubuntu.com/questions/8089/extracting-multiple-file-types-while-ignoring-errors

Comment: @aggitan: sure. btw you should mention cross-posting on both sites